# Removal of ACE_Singleton with some other Singleton class from BOOST or C++14 class

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, c++14

We are migrating from `C++03` to `C++14` and it is the decision to go way from ACE lib. We mostly use ACE lib for Singleton objects and locks. So for locks we can use `mutex` from `C++11/14` but what would be the better replacement of ACE_SINGLETON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

class foo;

foo& get_foo();

class foo
{
    friend foo& get_foo();;
private:
    ~foo () { std::cout << "foo destroyed" << std::endl; }
    foo () { std::cout << "foo constructed" << std::endl; }
    foo(const foo&) = delete;
    foo& operator=(const foo&) = delete;
};

foo&
get_foo()
{
    static foo f;
    return f;
}

int
main()
{
    auto& f = get_foo();
}
```

If you are using Visual Studio, you need VS-2015 or later.

Thread-local statics have thread safe initialization in C++11 and forward.

**Update**

```
template <class T>
class Singleton
{
public:
    static T& getinstance()
    {
        static T t;
        return t;
    }
};
```

?

But in the final analysis, I'm a big fan of KISS.  And there's nothing much simpler than writing a `get_foo()` factory function for your singleton (thanks to thread-safe function local statics).  Since the language now supplies the hard part (thread safe initialization), `class Singleton<T>` adds little value imho.

Here is recent code I've written indicating that I practice what I'm saying:

https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/blob/master/src/tz.cpp#L573-L578

In this particular case I needed to have a quite complicated construction process for my singleton, and even the ability to occasionally re-initialize it.  But it still boiled down to a factory function wrapped around a function-local-static.

Comment: I want a template class like AC_SINGLETON which I just mention in the client class with like -
TYPE is my client class Singleton<TYPE>.
And when i call Singleton<TYPE>.getinstance() it returns a single object.

Comment: The Singleton template posted here should also work with CRTP - `class MyClass : public Singleton<MyClass> ...`  Just make sure to declare `Singleton<MyClass>` as a friend of `MyClass` if the default destructor is private.